# Transform from global coordinate system to a local

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, defined by a direction vector $$\vec n= \langle n_x,n_y,n_z\rangle$$ and a point $C(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)$. The direction of the normal unit vector $\vec n$ is described from plane's altitude and azimuth angles $\alpha, A$ respectively as: $$\vec n = \langle\cos(\alpha) \sin(A), \cos(\alpha)\cos(A), \sin(\alpha)\rangle.$$
Assume a point $P(X_P, Y_P, Z_P)$ which lies on the plane (e.g intersection point between a line and plane).

How can I convert point $P(X_P,Y_P,Z_P)$ from the global coordinate system to plane's local coordinate system and finally get $p(x_p, y_p, 0)$?

All uppercase $X,Y,Z$ refer to global coordinate system.

All lowercase $x,y,z$ to plane's local coordinate system.

Comment: In case it matters to you, the formulas in my answer give _a_ set of plane coordinates, not _the_ set of plane coordinates. (There does not exist a unique choice of plane coordinates.) These formulas are numerically unstable for planes whose normal vector is close to $\pm(0, 0, 1)$; for topological reasons, there's no way to avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: @user86418 Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n = \pm\langle 0, 0, 1\rangle$, then $Z_{P} = 0$ and your point is already in the desired form.

Otherwise, $u_{1} = \langle -\cos(A), \sin(A), 0\rangle$ and $u_{2} = n \times u_{1} = \langle -\sin(\alpha) \sin(A), -\sin(\alpha) \cos(A), \cos(\alpha)\rangle$ are an orthonormal basis for your plane, and
\begin{align*}
x_{P} &= (P - C) \cdot u_{1}
  = -(X_{P} - X_{1}) \cos(A) + (Y_{P} - Y_{1}) \sin(A), \\
y_{P} &= (P - C) \cdot u_{2}
  =  -(X_{P} - X_{1})\sin(\alpha) \sin(A) - (Y_{P} - Y_{1})\sin(\alpha) \cos(A) + (Z_{P} - Z_{1})\cos(\alpha).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm trying a case: http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m1110279

Plane from:

Point: $C = (-4, 2, 1)$

Normal vector: $H = \langle-0.12, -0.24, 0.86\rangle$

Point A on plane: $A = (2.67, -1.51, 0.95)$

I compute:

$a = arcsin(H_2) = 1.03$


  $A =
\begin{cases}
2\pi - \frac{H_1}{cos(a)},  & \text{if A $\lt$ 0} \\
\frac{H_1}{cos(a)}, & \text{if A $\ge$ 0}
\end{cases} = 4.22$

$u_1 = \langle-0.47, -0.88, 0\rangle, u_2 = \langle0.76, 0.4, 0.22\rangle$



And at last:

$x_e = 6.12$,

$y_e = 3.63$

But $\lVert e\rVert = 7.22 \ne \lVert CE\rVert = 7.54$

Did I get something wrong?

Comment: @T81: It appears your $H$ isn't a unit vector. (To fix this, divide $H$ by $\|H\|$. :) Possibly as a result, $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ aren't unit vectors. (With $u_{1}$ the issue may be round-off error, but $\|u_{2}\| \approx 0.8866$.) Actually, your $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ aren't orthogonal, either....

Comment: I'd assumed you knew the altitude and azimuth of your plane. :) Rather than using inverse trig functions: If $n = (a, b, c)$ is a unit vector, then $$u_{1} = \frac{(-b, a, 0)}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}},\qquad u_{2} = n \times u_{1} = \frac{(-ca, -cb, a^{2} + b^{2})}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}}.$$Then use $x_{P} = (P - C) \cdot u_{1}$ and $y_{P} = (P - C) \cdot u_{2}$.

Comment: Great! Indeed $H$ was not a unit vector. When converted and proceed either with the invert trig functions or using the above recommendation, I got $x_e = 7.54$, $y_e = -0.16$ and $\lVert e\rVert =  7.54$. Actually I prefer to avoid inverse trig functions. Thank you again! :)

Comment: In case I want the result $x_e = -7.54$, $y_e = +0.16$ can I go: $u_1 = \frac{(b, -a, 0)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$?

Comment: @T81: "Yes". :) (In more detail, multiplying $u_{1}$ by $-1$ also multiplies $u_{2} = n \times u_{1}$ by $-1$, which changes the signs of both coordinates.)